# UIProgressView track status of download ios monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, progress-bar, threadpool

I have been looking all over to see how to update progressview while image downloads. My current download code is

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RetrieveImage),(object)cell);

private void RetrieveImage(object val)
{
CustomViewCell cell = (CustomViewCell)val;
int i = 0;
//lock(_imgDict){
//if ( !_imgDict.ContainsKey(cell.imageUrl) )
//{
     NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(cell.imageUrl);
     NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(nsUrl);
     if (data != null) {
InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    cell.imgImageView.Image = new UIImage (data);
    i++;
    cell.ProgressBar.Progress = (float)(i + 1) / 3; 
    });
    //_imgDict.Add (cell.imageUrl, data);
} 
}
```

All this does is show the progress bar on top of the image with 75% complete. not really showing progress being updated? How do I use this current thread to update the progress bar while the image is still being downloaded. I seen other examples but not really able to follow them.

**Edit:**

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(RetrieveImage),(object)cell); 

 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
 using(var client = new WebClient())
 {
client.DownloadProgressChanged+= 
 delegate(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.TotalBytesToReceive != 0) {
        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        cell.PG.Progress = e.BytesReceived / 
                e.TotalBytesToReceive;
              });
             }
     };
client.DownloadDataCompleted += 
delegate(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
      if(e.Result!=null)
          {
                NSData data = NSData.FromArray(e.Result);
           _imgDict.Add (cell.ImageUrl, data);
         InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
                  cell.PG.Hidden=true;
                  cell.imgImageView.Image =  UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
            });
     }
    else
    {
        InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        cell.PG.Hidden=true;
                    cell.imgImageView.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("Images/retrydownload.png");
                    });
    }
 }; 
    client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(cell.ImageUrl));
}
```

now with this updated code I do not see the progress bar while download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hardcoding the progress to 75%. 
In your code `i == 0`, so `(float)(i + 1) / 3 = 1/3 = 0.75`.

`NSData.FromUrl()` does not support progress handling the easy way. If you want to stick with the native stuff, you will have to subclass `NSUrlConnection` and and override `DidReceiveData()`.

Alternatively I recommend you use WebClient instead, which is the .NET way of downloading something:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (args) =>
{
Console.WriteLine("Downloaded {0} of {1} bytes", args.BytesReceived, args.TotalBytesToReceive);
};

client.DownloadFileCompleted += (args) => Console.WriteLine("Download finished.");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("someurl"), "somelocalpath");
```

Comment: I'd avoid WebClient since it carries out most of its work on the UI Thread and Rather stick to this: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient

Comment: Well the reason I prefer my way over ios way over the .Net way is that if the url is not valid, NSData = null; which I do something different to the UI, .net does not work the same for the webclient. how would I go about to incorporate NSLUrlConnection into my code, could you provide some direction

Comment: Also how do I hide the progressbar when the file is complete, because changing the Frame to (0,0,0,0) doesn't quite do it

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Doesn't matter, it's an async method. And nobody stops you from using the sync version in another Thread.

Comment: @Jake I don't understand what you're trying to say with your comment. And if you want to know how to hide the progressbar, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Krumelur Of course it matters. Just because a method is async there's not guarantee that it carries most of its work out on background thread. You might want to read on SynchronizationContexts.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebClient.cs#L1097 - I see a `new Thread()`. But yes, it initializes and blocks a bit in the beginning eg when resolving the host name.

Comment: @Krumelur I just looked at this way and this way will not work, .DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("someurl"), "somelocalpath"); is looking to save a local file from the download. I want to set the file download to my uimageview.image, not create local files in the solution

Comment: Found that I can use downloaddatasync, but that always returns null in the DownloadFileCompleted Eventhandler

Comment: Ok After troubleshooting I figured out that the DownLoadProgress had errors in it so now its fixed, but I never see the progress bar change updates. I will post my updated code

Comment: @OliverWeichhold @Krumelur do you know that `HttpClient` can use the native network handler ? `var client = new HttpClient (new CFNetworkHandler ());` see http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2013/Jun-07.html

Comment: @StephaneDelcroix Yeah, that's what the ModernHttpClient is doing that Oliver linked.github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient

Comment: I mean, it's supported out of the box, without ModernHttpClient